# ASP.NET access controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to build an ASP.NET 3.5 website that allows users to log in and browse a couple of pages. I would like to restrict certain users to be able to view certain pages but I'm having trouble coming up with a custom and flexible system. I have seen MS's version of this but it's not what I am looking for. Can anyone direct me to some good online articles or even a video tutorial so I can do further research. Thanks!

P.S. I have tried creating a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page which does some checking but it's getting messy. All my other pages inherit from that common page. Is this a common practice? How have you guys solved this problem in the past?

Comment: Can you explain how the MSFT version is insufficient for your needs?  It'll help us understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I am still very new to ASP.NET so I wasn't sure if the Membership, Role etc classes can work with what I have. I am taking over a project with an already existing table of users and roles and I need to create a system where an admin can create new roles and assign them to certain users. Finally I need to restrict not only pages but certain elements within a page (I.E. a GridView of data) to certain users. For example: 

`if user == admin 
     show account numbers 
else 
     show nothing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement this would be, Forms Authentication coupled with Custom Role Provider.

Hope you know, for Forms Authentication to work, you need not have to use the Complete Database Setup that MS uses to Authenticate.

You can simply have your own Database and Validate a user yourself, and just set the cookie.

```
String UserName = "CoolGuy";
Boolean isValidUser = YourClass.YourMethod(UserName);
if (isValidUser)
{ FormsAuthentication.setAuthCookie(UserName, false); }
```

This will authenticate the user "CoolGuy" for the session, provided YourMethod returns true.

You can use this, coupled with custom role provider.  This gives you the facility to check User.IsInRole("Role");  in your code.

To Start with CustomRoleProvider.. here is a good reference... http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/17/CreateCustomRoleProviderASPNETRolePermissionsSecurity.aspx

- Raja

Comment: Thanks Raja. Do you know how to forward the user to a page other than the Default page after a successful log in? I have been using Response.Redirect but I have seen the FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage method. 

For example, after a user succcesfully logs in on the Default.aspx page I want to fwd them on to Orders.aspx.

Comment: If the redirect page is going to be the same. The convenient way is to use Response.Redirect()....  This must be after setting Forms Authentication Cookie.

Comment: Incase a user generally requests a secured page directly (say asd.aspx)...  Since the page is secured it will redirect to login page... After successful login if you want to take the user back asd.aspx... you need to use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing the exact details of your app, one thing you could use is the Role Manager built into the Membership API.

Basically, you would create roles for each page and assign users to the roles (pages) you would want them to view.

In the code behind for each page, on the On_Load event, I would simply call the method

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole(rolePageName))
{
  //Continue page loading logic
}
{
  //Redirect or transfer the user elsewhere
}
```

For this kind of logic you may want to reconsider using an inherited page, otherwise you're going to have to come up with a way to retrieve the URL of the page and pass that into some long list of if-else or switch statements to call the proper `Roles.IsUserInRole` method.